# cordova downloads plugins twice

Tags: cordova

Cordova v7 adds plugins from config.xml into package.json `dependencies`. So they will downloaded twice:

1. `npm install` will download them into `node_modules`
2. `cordova prepare` will download them into `plugins`

That's the explanation of that? Is there way to download they once?

I don't store plugins and platforms dirs in repo and restore them on build server because each build changes config.xml(version, package) and icons.

commands I execute on each build:

```
rm -rf plugins platforms
npm install
cordova prepare
prepare files # my custom command: creates signing files and apply icons
cordova build android release
cordova build ios release
```

versions:

```
 cordova -v
 7.0.1
 npm -v
 4.6.1
```

Comment: also: platforms are downloaded twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As outlined in the [Cordova 7.0.0 release blog post](https://cordova.apache.org/news/2017/05/04/cordova-7.html), `cordova@7` now uses npm to install both platforms and plugins by default.

To revert to pre-Cordova 7 behaviour, use the `--nofetch` option:

```
cordova platform add android --nofetch
cordova prepare --nofetch
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-device --nofetch
```